# Схема данных и связи

Tags: база-данных

Здраствуйте помогите пожалуйста.

Не могу разобраться как настроить связи между таблицами в бд.

Есть сущность1 в - которой содержаться 30 других сущностей не больше, и не меньше.

Каждая из этих тридцати сущностей  должна содержать по две сущности.

В базе данных мне надо сохранять состояние сущности1 а также историю замены её тридцати элементов.

Comment: Какую БД (а вернее, СУБД) используете? Реляционку? NoSql?

Comment: Реляционную Postgres

Comment: Мало данных для осмысленного ответа.

Comment: сущность1 — в одной таблице, сущность2 — в другой. ну и ещё отдельную таблицу для истории изменений сущность2. и, если требуется, то и отдельную таблицу для истории изменений сущность1. в чём проблема-то? в недостатке информации? ну, начните с [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85), и обязательно [про нф](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0)

Comment: Какие данные ещё нужны?

Comment: Вы наверное  не верно прочитали там вобще-то три сущности.  Спасибо за ссылку на викепедию.

Comment: я думал, что это очевидно, что нужны отдельные таблицы и под сущность3, и под сущность4, и под сущность5, и т.д.

Comment: Дам больше информации, что конкретно у меня не получается позже.

Comment: *Есть сущность1 в - которой содержаться 30 других сущностей не больше, и не меньше.* Может ли экземпляр сущности-2 (та, которых 30 штук в сущности-1) существовать без привязки к экземпляру сущности-1? Может ли один и тот же экземпляр сущности-2 содержаться в одном экземпляре сущности-1 более одного раза (и если да - он считается как один или сколько раз входит)? а в разных экземплярах сущности-1? Каковы вообще правила контроля целостности данных?

Comment: Вообще схема "30 других сущностей не больше, и не меньше" - это не то, что обеспечивается стандартными системами контроля целостности. То есть потребуется дополнительная кастомная логика, скорее всего построенная на триггерах, и к тому же придётся вводить понятие существующей, но невалидной, записи. Или придётся отходить от нормальных форм - а это вообще неясно где и как аукнется.

Comment: Спасибо я понял -что геморрой. В этом у меня и была проблема. Позже опишу бизнес задачу может будут какие-то предложения по формированию бд.